# Spring GCP firestore issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to implement firestore in spring boot. i added the following dependency but getting the error below

dependency added

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-data-firestore:1.2.8.RELEASE'
    implementation("com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-data-firestore")
    implementation("com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-firestore")
```

the error i am getting is

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in org.springframework.cloud.gcp.logging.LoggingWebMvcConfigurer required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gcp.core.GcpProjectIdProvider' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gcp.core.GcpProjectIdProvider' in your configuration.


> Task :FleetioIntegrationApplication.main() FAILED
```

I tried different versions but no use